# Angular Template Driven Forms

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am learning angular Template driven form and applying validations.
I wrote one code and it is working fine.
Just want to know what is lname.errors.required that is used for putting validation.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" name="lastname" 
ngModel  minlength="5" maxlength="10" required #lname="ngModel">
           
            <span *ngIf="lname.touched && !lname.valid">

                <span *ngIf="lname.errors.required">
                    Last name is required.
                </span>
                    
                <span *ngIf="lname.value!='' && lname.value.length<5 || lname.value.length>10">
                    Minimum Character should be 5 and Maximum characters should be 10
    
                 </span>
        
            </span>
```

What to know the meaning of syntax: why/what is the meaning of .error.required

```
  <span *ngIf="lname.errors.required">
                    Last name is required.
                </span>
```

Comment: go to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) the best reference, add details on what confuses you after going through the docs!

Comment: error is an object type and contains all errors of the specified control as property, Ex: If required is attribute is added to the control and control field is empty then required property is added with true value in the error object like error: { required : true } otherwise if control not have any error then error:null